# Route slug to subdomain symfony 1.4

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, doctrine, symfony-1.4

first of all, since i haven't done anything it may come wrong asking before coding, but i will try to explain my issue with pseudo code. 
I want to route each of my slug(category) to related sub domain. 
my site(application) for routes any of the categories to a sub page under the domain for the moment as follows:

> slug_name (goes to)-> mysite.com/slug_name 
>   (it is done via routing configurations, for example cinemas slug is shown as mysite.com/cinemas)

But i want to show the same results under **cinemas.mysite.com**

i followed [routing - symfony 1.4 jobbet](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/05?orm=Doctrine)  but couldn't realize any solution.
Note: subdomain is under the same server. Please share any suggestions&ideas, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check symfony1.4 plugins, for example:

```
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDomainRoutePlugin
```

it should help You start.